# ¿Usar un objeto zip unzip el contenido de forma permanente?

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip

Tengo dos conjuntos de datos:

```
x:  [(1, -14580.0, -3389.0), (1, -18403.0, 19052.0), (1, -31845.0, -39952.0), (1, -10634.0, -220.0), (1, -9180.0, 18411.0), (1, -27952.0, -8415.0), (1, -25686.0, 8325.0), (1, -22570.0, 8041.0), (1, -34124.0, -5791.0), (1, -20119.0, 2468.0), (1, -12164.0, 53333.0), (1, -14587.0, -66443.0), (1, -5928.0, -7212.0), (1, -25489.0, 5610.0), (1, -33283.0, -18741.0), (1, -18729.0, 1234.0), (1, -25495.0, -361.0), (1, -33315.0, -6149.0), (1, -28093.0, 11441.0), (1, -36642.0, -3513.0), (1, -26365.0, 8214.0), (1, -36366.0, 10423.0)] 
ts: 
 [131479.0, 128090.0, 147142.0, 107190.0, 106970.0, 125381.0, 116966.0, 125291.0, 133332.0, 127541.0, 130009.0, 183342.0, 116899.0, 109687.0, 115297.0, 96556.0, 97790.0, 97429.0, 91280.0, 102721.0, 99208.0, 107422.0, 117845.0, 168755.0, 110971.0, 84198.0, 82014.0, 77827.0, 72295.0, 64114.0, 63187.0, 66079.0, 72843.0, 71056.0]
value:  422080882435.25397
```

y quiero hacer una regresión lineal múltiple para predecir el beta.

```
import random

def dot(v,w):
  return sum(v_i*w_i for v_i, w_i in zip(v,w))

def predict(x_i, beta):
  """assumes that the first element of each x_i is one"""
  return dot(x_i, beta)

def error(x_i, y_i, beta):
  return y_i - predict(x_i, beta)

def squarred_error(x_i, y_i, beta):
  return error(x_i, y_i, beta)**2

def squarred_error_gradient(x_i, y_j, beta):
  return [-2 * x_ij * error(x_i, y_j, beta) 
          for x_ij in x_i]

def in_random_order(data):
  """generator that returns the elements if data in random order"""
  indexes = [i for i, _ in enumerate(data)] # create a list of indexes
  random.shuffle(indexes) # suffle them
  for i in indexes:
    # print("data[i]: ", data[i])
    return data[i]

def minimize_stochastic(target_fn, gradient_fn, x,y, theta_0, alpha_0=0.01):
  data = zip(x,y)
  theta = theta_0  #initial guess
  almpah = alpha_0  # initial step size
  min_theta, min_value = None, float('inf') # the minimum so far
  iterations_with_no_improvment = 0

  # if we ever go 100 iterations with no improvment, stop
  while iterations_with_no_improvment < 100:
    value = sum(target_fn(x_i, y_i, theta) for x_i, y_i in data)
    print("value: ", value)

    if value < min_value:
      # if we've found a new minimum, remember it
      # and go back to the original step size
      min_theta, min_value = theta, value
      iterations_with_no_improvment = 0
      alpha = alpha_0
    else:
      # otherwise we're not improving, so try shrinking the step size
      iterations_with_no_improvment +=1
      alpha *=0.9

    # and take a gradient step for each of the data points
    # print("data: ", [x for x in data])
    # print("data: ", data)
    for x_i, y_i in in_random_order(data):
      gradient_i = gradient_fn(x_i, y_i, theta)
      theta = vector_substract(theta, scalar_multiply(alpha_gradient_i))
  return min_theta

def estimate_beta(x,y):
  beta_initial = [random.random() for x_i in x[0]]
  return minimize_stochastic(squarred_error,
                             squarred_error_gradient,
                             x,y,
                             beta_initial,
                             0.001)

random.seed(0)
beta = estimate_beta(x, ts)
```

Sin embargo, parece que `in_random_order(data)` no funciona porque el data es un `zip` que esta `None`. En efecto obtengo:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-109-c0f3fa276b50> in <module>()
     69 
     70 random.seed(0)
---> 71 beta = estimate_beta(x, ts)

1 frames
<ipython-input-109-c0f3fa276b50> in minimize_stochastic(target_fn, gradient_fn, x, y, theta_0, alpha_0)
     54     # print("data: ", [x for x in data])
     55     # print("data: ", data)
---> 56     for x_i, y_i in in_random_order(data):
     57       gradient_i = gradient_fn(x_i, y_i, theta)
     58       theta = vector_substract(theta, scalar_multiply(alpha_gradient_i))

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Para poder replicar tu error (ejecutar el código que das) hace falta al menos el valor de `ts`

Comment: @abulafia Me disculpe, Acabo de editar. Era la antigua "y". Es una serie temporal que quiero predecir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Qué significa el error?

Ya que el error salta en la línea que dice:

```
for x_i, y_i in in_random_order(data):
```

el problema es que `in_random_order(data)` ha generado como resultado `None` (o un iterable cuyo primer elemento es `None` en cuyo caso fallaría el desempaquetado con el mismo mensaje de error).

## ¿Por qué sucede?

¿Por qué estará devolviendo `None` esa la función? Veamos su código:

```
def in_random_order(data):
  """generator that returns the elements if data in random order"""
  indexes = [i for i, _ in enumerate(data)] # create a list of indexes
  random.shuffle(indexes) # suffle them
  for i in indexes:
    return data[i]
```

Vemos que debería estar devolviendo `data[i]`, pero el `data` que le estás pasando se inicializa en esta otra línea, de otra función:

```
data = zip(x,y)
```

O sea que `data` no es una lista, sino el resultado de un `zip()`. Ocurre que este resultado, aunque es un iterable, **no es indexable**. No puedes usarlo como si fuera una lista para tratar de obtener su resultado i-ésimo, como puedes comprobar con este experimento:

```
>>> test = zip(x, y)
>>> test[1]
TypeError: 'zip' object is not subscriptable
```

Entonces la función debería haber generado esa excepción al llegar al `return data[i]`. Sin embargo no ha generado tal excepción sino que ha retornado `None`¿cómo pudo suceder esto?

Sólo hay una forma. No llegó nunca a ejecutar esa línea. Y ésto solo puede suceder si este bucle:

```
  for i in indexes:
    return data[i]
```

no itera ni una sola vez. Es decir, si el iterable `indexes` está vacío. Esto es de hecho lo que ocurre como puedes comprobar si añades un `print(indexes)` delante del bucle.

Esto significa por tanto que el valor de `data` que le llega es un objeto `zip()` **agotado**.

## ¿Qué es un iterable agotado?

Es un iterable por el que ya has iterado una vez. Los iterables en python, una vez llegas a su final, no puedes volver a iterar por ellos. Rápida demostración:

```
>>> a = zip(x, y)
>>> test = [ v for v in a ]
# La línea anterior no da problemas. `a` es un iterable, y podemos iterar por él
# Si imprimiéramos ahora el valor de `test` veríamos todos sus elementos
# No lo hago porque es largo

>>> len(test)
22

>>> test2 = [ v for v in a ]
# Esta línea tampoco daría problemas, pero ya que el objeto zip se ha agotado
# no se realizará niguna iteración. test2 resulta vacío

>>> len(test2)
0
```

Por tanto tu código itera sobre `data` en algún momento antes de pasarlo como parámetro a `in_random_order()`.

Efectivamente vemos que lo hace en la línea:

```
    value = sum(target_fn(x_i, y_i, theta) for x_i, y_i in data)
```

Es aquí donde `data`  queda agotado, y por tanto al pasarlo después como parámetro  a `in_random_order()` ya no se obtienen más elementos al iterar sobre `data`.

## ¿Y si quiero iterar más veces? ¿no se puede?

Esto nos lleva a tu pregunta. Seguramente tú te sospechabas que estaba pasando algo de esto pues preguntabas "usar un objeto zip de forma permanente", que entiendo que viene a significar que quieres iterar sobre él varias veces.

Ya hemos visto que sobre un iterador sólo se puede iterar una vez. Pero si a partir del iterador construyes una lista, matas dos pájaros de un tiro ya que si `data` fuese una lista:

- Podrías iterar múltiples veces por ella (porque cada vez que lo intentas Python construye para ella un nuevo iterador)
- Podrías acceder a `data[i]`, resolviendo otro problema que tenías antes.

Así pues, basta cambiar esta asignación:

```
data = zip(x, y)
```

por esta otra:

```
data = list(zip(x, y))
```

El constructor `list()` itera por los contenidos del objeto `zip()`, creando con ellos una lista.

## Pero hay más errores

Con ese cambio ahora rompe por otra razón:

```
---> 57     for x_i, y_i in in_random_order(data):
     58       gradient_i = gradient_fn(x_i, y_i, theta)
     59       theta = vector_substract(theta, scalar_multiply(alpha_gradient_i))

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Ahora resulta que `return data[i]` tiene más valores de los que se esperaban (se esperaban 2, uno para `x_i` y otro para `y_i`. En vez de eso se obtienen tres. ¿Por qué?

En este caso el error es más sutil. Y es que tu función `in_random_order()` no hace en realidad lo que tú querías. Pretendías que devolviera los elementos de `data` en orden aleatorio, pero en realidad sólo te devuelve el primer elemento de `data`, debido a que en este bucle:

```
  for i in indexes:
    return data[i]
```

retornas inmediatamente en la primera iteración. Así que la función en realidad devuelve `data[indexes[0]]` y termina. Lo que devuelve será una tupla de este estilo: `((1, 2, 3), 4)` con un elemento de `x` y otro de `y`.

El bucle `for x_i, y_i in ....` iterará sobre esa tupla, que tiene dos elementos, por tanto hará dos iteraciones. En la primera de ellas encontrará el valor `(1,2,3)` que intentará asignar a `x_i, y_i` y por eso rompe.

El problema aquí es que tu función `in_random_order()` debería ser un generador, pero al no contener instrucciones `yield` es una función normal.

Es decir, debes cambiar el `return` por un `yield`:

```
def in_random_order(data):
  """generator that returns the elements if data in random order"""
  indexes = [i for i, _ in enumerate(data)] # create a list of indexes
  random.shuffle(indexes) # suffle them
  for i in indexes:
    yield data[i]
```

Otra versión más simple sería que en lugar de ir devolviendo con `yield` los elementos cambiados de orden, directamente devuelva una lista completa con los elementos desordenados. Es decir, puedes sacar una copia de `data`, desordenarla, y devolverla:

```
def in_random_order(data):
  aux = data[:]
  random.shuffle(aux)
  return aux
```

Cualquiera de estas soluciones arregla todos los problemas que se pueden arreglar de momento, pues aparece uno nuevo `NameError: name 'vector_substract' is not defined, pero ese ya no lo puedo solucionar con el código que proporcionas.